# Best pattern for a monthly billing cycle

Tags: c#, datetime, billing

I wrote some code for my new billing system. The purpose is to bill the customer on the same day each month. (not the 1st or last day of the month)

```
static bool NeedToBill(DateTime planLastBilled, DateTime cycleDate)
    {
        // is today the same date as the cycleDate AND is was the planLastBilled not the same day as today?
        if (DateTime.UtcNow.Day.Equals(cycleDate.Day) && !DateTime.UtcNow.Day.Equals(planLastBilled))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

The 2 pitfalls are:

1. If his cycleDate.Day is the 31 and the current month only has 29 days
2. cycleDate is Feb 29 2012 - he will only get billed on leap years

Is there a common best practice here?

so it seems like there's a bunch things to check

1. has this account already been billed this month?
2. does the cycle day exists in the current month
3. is the cycle day greater than or equal to    the current date (this is ideal if
   the transaction failed the day    before)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe I have been totally **over**-thinking this. 
This is simple and covers everything:

```
bool NeedToBill = ((DateTime.UTCNow – LastBillDate) >= 30 Days)
```

It will not necessarily bill on the exact same day, however it's close enough.
This also adds flexibility if the transaction was denied for a day, or if the scheduled task was not ran for 1 day the next time it runs it will pick it up.

Comment: Are you sure this works?  It seems to me you will shift the billing date ~5 days every year, eventually overcharging your customers (1 extra bill every 6 years).  Sounds like a nice case for a class action lawsuit if your company has enough subscribers...

Comment: DateTime.AddMonths takes into account leap years and different EOM dates.

Answer (score 8):

Only allow the choice of a billing day between **1 - 28**.  In my experience this is how most credit card / loan companies deal with it when given a choice.

Comment: While this works, it's not that big of a deal to support the 29, 30 and 31st.

Comment: True - but it simplifies it for everyone involed.  The OP asked for billing on the same day every month, so this is the only possible answer.

Answer (score 2):

What does the same day each month mean?

If I am a customer, I want to be billed on the 16th each month. No problem. If I want to be billed on the 31st on each month the obvious issue is not all months have 31 days as you've pointed out in your question.

Why not check the current month for the number of days. If it has less than 31 days, make the last day of the month the bill date.

Is there more to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say make him choose between 1-28, or any day but charge on the last day on the month if the current month has less days than the chosen day of month.

Comment: they don't choose cycle date = date account created

Comment: well then the same thing, make it the day they created the account or the last day of the month if the current month has fewer days than the day of the month they created the account on